# How to reduce Qt Application CPU usage for multithread application?

Tags: multithreading

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ruct.png)I have one Qt based console application with 4 threads are running concurrently and CPU usage is around 60%.
I need to reduces CPU usage around 8% to 10% . Application has events in 5millis

Can anybody provide some code sample or application architecture time splitting for manage multi thread application[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTJVk.png)

Require generic multithreading for 2 or 5 millis polling tasks for multithreading operation.

Comment: Well there is clearly not enough information to help you. Like for example what the threads are doing during 60% of the time. You need to profile your application in the first place. There is no generic solution to solve all performance issue besides the basic profiling+analysis+optimization feedback-loop.

Comment: hi there, i just need some generic sample code or idea about  4 threads are running in polling mode in multi threading operation that cause excessive cpu usage